# Compare two Values across two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two landfill disposal tables (DW and VT) in two separate SQL server databases with nearly identical information in them. I am trying to merge them into the VT table. The table in DW has the most current information and looks like this:

```
TicketNumber-----------ContainerID    
------12345------------------12    
------12345------------------17    
------12345------------------22    
------23456------------------12   
------23456------------------14    
------23456------------------32    
------23456------------------12
```

The table in VT looks like this:

```
TicketNumber-----------ContainerID------Pickups    
------12345------------------12--------------1    
------12345------------------17--------------1    
------23456------------------12--------------1
```

I want the combined VT table to look like this:

```
TicketNumber-----------ContainerID------Pickups    
------12345------------------12---------------1    
------12345------------------17---------------1   
------12345------------------22---------------1    
------23456------------------12---------------2    
------23456------------------14---------------1    
------23456------------------32---------------1
```

The problem is that there is a bit of overlap between the two, and I only want to insert the missing rows from DW into the VT table, but I can't get my where clause to compare two different values jointly. It is comparing each value separately.

Also, I want to count the number of identical records in DW and put that count into the [Pickups] column (Ticket 23456 container 12).  I need to ensure that any DW rows that DO NOT exist in VT are inserted into that table with the correct count, and if they DO exist in VT, I want to update [Pickups] to the correct count.

This is the code I have so far:

```
  INSERT INTO [VT]
 (TicketNumber, ContainerID, Pickups)
SELECT DISTINCT
  DW.[TICKET NUMBER],
  DW.[CONTAINER ID],
  '??????', --Not sure how to code this to count rows.
 FROM [DW]
 WHERE ?????
```

These tables are HUGE (think over a million rows in DW), so keep that in mind. I tried a WHERE NOT EXISTS and it ran for 20 minutes before I stopped it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just re-summarize the DW table?

```
truncate table vt;

insert into vt(TicketNumber, ContainerID, Pickups)
    select TicketNumber, ContainerID, count(*) as Pickups
    from Dw
    group by TicketNumber, ContainerID;
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You should try a merge/update statement.
First, I would alter the table VT to add the column "Pickup" (or otherwise create the table VT_final in which you would put your results). 
Assuming that you added a column "Pickup" to your existing VT table, I would proceed this way :

```
;WITH DW_New AS
(
  SELECT 
    TicketNumber
    ,ContainerID
    ,Pickup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TicketNumber, COntainerID) --Let's count the "duplicate" lines from DW
  FROM DW (NOLOCK)
)
MERGE VT AS tgt
USING DW_New AS src
  ON src.ticketnumber = tgt.ticketnumber
  AND src.containerID = TGT.ContainerID

WHEN MATCHED AND --This is when you have already a line in VT containing the same ticket and container
(
  src.Pickup != tgt.Pickup
)
THEN UPDATE SET
tgt.Pickup = tgt.Pickup + src.Pickup --Here I assume that you want to add the "Pickup" value from DW to the existing VT "Pickup" value. Otherwise you can rework this.

WHEN NOT MATCHED --This is your insert : taking DW data into VT when VT doesn't contain an existing line for the container and ticket
THEN
  INSERT
  (
TicketNumber
,ContainerID
,Pickup
  )
 VALUES
 (
src.TicketNumber
,src.ContainerID
,src.Pickup
 )
```

;

Please note that I assumed that you might want to update the "pickup" value in VT if you run this several times, and I assumed that you would then just add the DW "Pickup" value. 
Of course, I am not sure whether you would "reset" (ie. truncate) the DW table every time you run this, so you might want to rework this to fit your needs.

**Edit**
Two things I forgot to mention in my answer :

- **different databases** : it's kind of obvious, but my code didn't mention any database. If you want this to work across different databases, make sure you put the DBs names in front of the tables
- **huge tables** : 1 million rows isn't really huge. It depends on your server and a lot of parameters of course, but MERGE/UPDATE statements are pretty fast and quite well designed to work over bigger datasets (I run them on tables that are 10s of millions of records, and with a lot more columns). It would be interesting for you to try to add indexes to those tables, in order to facilitate SQL-Server work.

I would try this index on your destination table (assuming you already have a Primary Key on it, meaning you cannot create other clustered indexes):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VT_Index] ON VT
(
    TicketNumber ASC,
    ContainerID ASC,
)
INCLUDE (Pickup) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB =   OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
```